# OpenSSL.NET DES Functions

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, openssl, 3des

I wan't to deal with 3DES algorithm using OpanSSL C# wrapper.
can anyone tell me where to find 3DES functions in OpenSSL.NET?
and how to encrypt and decrypt using shared secret key between the server and the client.

Comment: DES is useless if your adversary can spare a few hours of CPU time to brute force the key, so it is inadvisable to use it in new software.

Answer (score 1):

Use AES instead, it is more secure and faster on new CPUs with HW AES acceleration.
You can find the OpenSSL API at openssl.org, the openssl.net is a wrapper to the C API.